# "Jack thought him incapable"

Tags: grammar

Can I say "Jack thought him incapable" in English meaning, "Jack thought of him as of an incapable person" or is it completely wrong in English to say that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Jack thought him incapable.

That is, Jack thought he [some other person] was not capable.

Perfectly grammatical. A tad formal, or at least educated/literate. The more colloquial version is:

> Jack thought he was incapable.

You could also tack a prepositional phrase onto **incapable**:

> Jack thought him incapable of such treachery.